# Apontar para uma pasta antes de DOCUMENT ROOT?

Tags: php, apache, path

Abaixo segue a estrutura das pastas:

```
/home/web/site/public_html
```

Se eu der um echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Vou obter o caminho para public_html, mas eu gostaria de deixar alguns arquivos inacessíveis diretamente pela URL por isso estou colocando esses arquivos dentro da `/home/web/site` mas eu gostaria de não ter que usar `../../../` para voltar até chegar em `/site` e ter que ficar adivinhando quantas pastas eu devo voltar para chegar no destino, tem alguma forma mais fácil de apontar para uma pasta antes da default?

E se eu quiser chamar os arquivos para uma tag `img` ou `video` através do `src="algo..."` seria uma solução mais prática servir tais arquivos através de um script php e limitar as permissões do mesmo? Se sim como posso criá-lo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O servidor não "apontaria" pro diretório, afinal, ele não seria público. Mas dá pra carregar conteúdo privado pra um script `PHP`. Defina uma constante e faça uma espécie de "validação de acesso" na própria aplicação.

Como é possível fazer isso com imagens usando a biblioteca [`php-gd`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.image.php):

*imagem.php*:

```
<?php
defined('FILES') OR define('FILES', '/home/web/site/');
if($_GET['img']){
    $filename = FILES.$_GET['img'];
    if(file_exists($filename)){
        $file_info = getimagesize($filename);
        foreach ($file_info as $i => $v){
            if($v == 'image/png'){
                $mime = $v;
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            }
            elseif($v == 'image/jpg'){
                $mime = $v;
                $img = imagecreatefromjpg($filename);
            }
        }
        header("Content-type: " . $mime);
        imagepng($img);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else{
        echo 'Imagem nao localizada!';
    }
}
else{
    echo 'Imagem não definida!';
}
```

Basta passar o nome completo da imagem na url: `imagem.php?img=imagename.jpg`.

Para fazer streaming de vídeos, vale a pena estudar coisas como [VideoStream.php](https://gist.github.com/ranacseruet/9826293). Veja:

*stream.php*

```
<?php
include 'VideoStream.php';
defined('FILES') OR define('FILES', '/home/web/site/');
$video = new VideoStream(FILES.'videoname.mp4');
$video->start();
```

Você pode definir a segurança e as permissões adequadas no `PHP` e ele carrega o conteúdo pro navegador.

Comment: mas isso vai deixar os arquivos acessíveis através da url no navegador, não?

Comment: Vc tem razão. Os arquivos não ficam disponíveis para o servidor web, apenas para a aplicação (é isso, não é?). Editei a resposta ;)

Comment: se eu chamar a mesma por uma tag img funciona? exemplo src="<?FILES?>"/resto do caminho.jpg"

Comment: Não porque aí o arquivo precisaria ser público. Vc pode criar um script `php` que tenha permissão de acesso ao arquivo e retorne a imagem. algo como: *imagem.php?imagem=nomeimagem.jpg*.

Comment: Mas ai tornaria inviável já que o script precisaria ser acessível na web para eu chamar o mesmo através da url

Comment: Sim, mas não é inviável. Quem acessa o script não acessa necessariamente a imagem. E vc pode configurar o script para dar acesso mediante permissão (ou autenticação), ou validação de parâmetro, etc. Posso testar, mas recomendo que edite sua pergunta e informe (claramente) que, apesar de restritas, as imagens precisariam ser mostradas no navegador ;)

Comment: Editada, na verdade esses são arquivos de vídeo, por isso é importante que eles sejam acessíveis através das tags src mas não pelo caminho direto na url

Answer (score 2):

Um jeito simples é definir uma constante para o local que deseja.

```
define('PRIVATE_BASE', _DIR_.'/../');
```

Com isso basta chamar `PRIVATE_BASE` para montar a base do path.

Claro que isso vai depender de como é estruturado o aplicativo. Normalmente deve ter um arquivo único que serve de rota para todos os outros. O `index.php`, por exemplo.

Se não possuir um arquivo de rota, pode optar por um "config.php" ou coisa do tipo. Então inclua esse "config.php" nos arquivos que deseja obter a informação do path.

Note que ainda está usando o recuo de diretório. Mas usará apenas uma vez.

É preferível usar o recuo caso queira dar flexibilidade ao aplicativo.

Caso ainda queira definir o path estaticamente, esteja ciente que se precisar rodar o aplicativo num ambiente com estruturas diferentes, terá que editar manualmente os paths.

`define('PRIVATE_BASE', '/home/www/site/');`